# Mongoosastic: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

While syncrhonizing models with Mongoosastic I am receiving this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at
> setIndexNameIfUnset
> (/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js:239:29) at
> EmbeddedDocument.schemaIndex [as index]
> (/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js:385:5) at
> EmbeddedDocument.postSave
> (/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js:269:14) at next
> (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:198:31) at Kareem.execPost
> (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3) at
> /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/saveSubdocs.js:54:29 at each
> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/each.js:11:5) at
> model.
> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/saveSubdocs.js:53:5) at
> callMiddlewareFunction (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:482:23) at
> next (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:193:9) at next
> (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:212:9) at Kareem.execPost
> (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3) at _cb
> (/app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:307:15) at
> /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:400:5 at
> /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:324:11 at runMicrotasks
> ()

**1.) orderLineItem schema:**

```
let orderLineItemSchema = new mongodb.Schema({
    orderId: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    name: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    description: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    privateNotice: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    netPrice: { type: String, default: 0, es_indexed: true },
    taxPercent: { type: Number, default: 23, es_indexed: true },
    projectFile: { type: projectFileSchema, es_schema: projectFileSchema, es_indexed: true, es_type: 'nested', es_include_in_parent: true },
    component: { type: [componentSchema], es_indexed: true, es_type: 'nested', es_include_in_parent: true },
    additionalFiles: { type: [projectFileSchema], es_indexed: true, es_type: 'nested', es_include_in_parent: true },
    status: { type: orderLineItemStatusSchema, es_indexed: true },
    accepted: { type: Boolean, default: false, es_indexed: true },
    archived: { type: Boolean, default: false, es_indexed: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

**2.) projectFileSchema:**

```
let projectFileSchema = new mongodb.Schema({
    name: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    mimeType: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    path: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    archived: { type: Boolean, default: false, es_indexed: true }
});
```

**3.) component schema:**

```
let componentSchema = new mongodb.Schema({
    name: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    category: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    componentId: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    symbol: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    archived: { type: Boolean, default: false, es_indexed: true }
});
```

**4.) orderLineItemStatusSchema:**

```
let orderLineItemStatusSchema = new mongodb.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Utworzony'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

**5.) My synchronization code:**

```
const synchronize = (model) => {
    let stream = model.synchronize();

    stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
      // Logging success to the console
    });
    stream.on('close', function(){
      // Logging ...
    });
    stream.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = synchronize;
```

**6.) Here's how I use it:**

```
const mongodb = require('mongoose');
const mtastic = require('mongoosastic');
const esClient = require('../dependencies/elasticsearch');
const orderLineItemSchema = require('../schemas/OrderLineItem/OrderLineItem');
const synchronizer = require('../helpers/synchronizer'); // This is the synchronization function

orderLineItemSchema.plugin(mtastic, {
    esClient: esClient
});

let OrderLineItem = mongodb.model('OrderLineItem', orderLineItemSchema);

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    synchronizer(OrderLineItem);
}, 10000);

module.exports = OrderLineItem;
```

It is the exact same way I synchronize other models in my app but only this one returns that error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you get a "fuller" stack trace?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Sadly I don't have the full stack trace right now because after I deleted everything from my MongoDB and then restarted everything this error stopped happening. That obviously isn't the solution, I just needed the app to work properly for presentation purposes.

Comment: I hear ya but we'll need more detail to debug this.

Comment: @JoeSorocin I managed to get the same error. Now I edited the question with the full stack trace Node is giving me.

Comment: Can you also show what `orderLineItemSchema` looks like please?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Yes, I editted the question to add all schemas relevant to the `orderLineItemSchema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/441) [issues](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/380) closed without a solution in the mongoosastic repository, suggesting that this is very likely a bug in the library that may not have a solution in user code.

What those issues and yours have in common is the use of subdocuments, and a quick glance at the library's source code suggests that it may be indeed related to an improper handling of that case.

A look at the test suite of the library also does not show any tests covering this scenario, further suggesting that it may simply not be supported.

Comment: This is most likely the best answer I will get for this issue. I've been looking for a way to fix this error with no luck for such a long time that I am willing to believe this might be a library problem. Thank you very much for researching the closed issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear [from the source code](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/blob/558ba1a486ae1efdb0a48dba279d69118679d3c5/lib/mongoosastic.js#L385) why the `modelName` would be `undefined`...

In any event, each `mongoosastic` model constructor [accepts an `index` parameter](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/blob/master/docs/README.md#modelpluginmongoosastic-options) so I'd declare it when I'm registering the plugin:

```js
...
orderLineItemSchema.plugin(mtastic, {
    esClient: esClient,
    index: 'orders-index`     // <---
});

let OrderLineItem = mongodb.model('OrderLineItem', orderLineItemSchema);
...
```